# Getting representation geometry created by rules (not manually overrided) using ArcObjects.net?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.3, representation

I have feature class with representation rules and now need to extract representation geometry from selected features.
If representation geometry is manually overrided, I can get it just using `IRepresentation.Shape` property:

```cs
IFeatureLayer layer = someLayerMethod();
IGeoFeatureLayer geoLayer = (IGeoFeatureLayer)layer;
IFeatureClass mapFeatureClass = layer.FeatureClass;

ICursor cursor = (ICursor)mapFeatureClass.Search(null, false);

IFeatureSelection selection = (IFeatureSelection)layer;
ISelectionSet selectionSet = selection.SelectionSet;

selectionSet.Search(null, false, out cursor);
IFeature mapFeature = (cursor as IFeatureCursor).NextFeature();

while (mapFeature != null)
{
    if (geoLayer.Renderer is IRepresentationRenderer)
    {
        IRepresentationClass repClass = (geoLayer.Renderer as IRepresentationRenderer).RepresentationClass;
        IRepresentation rep = repClass.GetRepresentation(mapFeature, mapContext);

        if (rep.Shape.GeometryType == esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon)
            doSomeAction(rep.Shape); // <-- overrided geometry
    }
    mapFeature = (cursor as IFeatureCursor).NextFeature();
}
```

And if geometry is not overrided but changed by representation rules (`Smooth`, `Donut`, `Simplify` etc), `IRepresentation.Shape` property returns original feature geometry. Other shapes properties (`ShapeCopy`, `ShapeEdit`) also returns original geometry.

How can I get geometry that was created by representation rule using ArcObjects.NET?
Or may be there is some way in Arcpy?

Comment: I'm also very interested in getting representation geometry.
Did you find finally a solution?
Best regards

Comment: Are you calling the UpdateFeature method after the shape is altered? Also, if you want it to persist you will need to call IFeature.Store

Comment: We are also looking for a process that will let us get access to the representation geometry in the override field. Has anyone got access to this via ArcObjects or otherwise?